# How do I use the Re Module with python to extract all punctuation tokens?

Tags: python, punctuation

I want to extract all punctuation tokens from a text with the re module. How can I do this?

Comment: use import string; string.punctuation

Comment: So what I've done know is this:

import string

p = [x.punctuation for x in words]

but unfortunaly doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()"
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> for p in punctuation:
...     if p in text:
...             print p
...
```

It will print all punctuation characters from text.

```
!
#
$
%
&
(
)
*
@
^
```

OR

```
>>> text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()"
>>> [char for char in punctuation if char in text]
['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '@', '^']
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it with the `re` module, but you can use list-comprehension:

```
from string import punctuation
old_string = "This, by the way, has some punctuation!"
new_string = "".join(char for char in old_string if char in punctuation)
print(new_string)
#,,!
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it does in fact answer the question.